# C# Null References while serializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

When serializing, how do you handle backer variables? Mine keep on turning up null, as in the following example:

```
[DataContract]
public Person
{
     public Person()
     {
         //a break point here doesn't get called in time - I try to use _myList and get an exception first. :(
         _myList = new string[3];
     }

    private string[] _myList {get; set;} = new string[3];  // Will be filled: {"Bob", "The", "Builder"};

    [DataMember]
    public string Occupation
    {
        get { return _myList[2]; }
        set {_myList[2] = value; }
    }

}


SerializeFunction(Person Bob, string filePath = @"C:\Temp\BobTheBuilder.xml")
{
     DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
     using(XmlWriter xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath))
     {
         serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, bob);
         xmlWriter.Flush();
     }
     using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
     {
         // This throws an exception, because _myList is null
         Person readInBob = deserializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
     }        
}
```

I get an exception when I try to read Bob back in, because the backer property _myList doesn't get initialized. How do you guys handle situations like this?

Comment: There's no reason to use a list like that. Why don't you use `publist string Occupateion{get;set;}`?

Comment: True. I am simply trying to create a simple understandable example here. In reality, the backer variables are a range of things, from thread safe wrappers to complex dictionaries.

Comment: That's even worse. In any case, the simplification results in something that shouldn't throw an NRE - an OutOfRange exception is more likely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement `IXmlSerializable`, you gain the control to do whatever you need to. Replace the person class above with:

```
public Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    private string[] _myList {get; set;} = new string[3];

    public string Occupation
    {
        get { return _myList[2]; }
        set {_myList[2] = value; }
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() => null;

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
         //THIS IS THE KEY LINE:
         _myList = new string[3];// you can do any initialization you need before actually reading.

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.NodeType != XmlNoteType.Element)
                continue;

            string propertyName = reader.Name; // we have arrived at an element.
            reader.Read(); // we have the property name, now get it's value

            switch(propertyName)
            {
                case nameof(Occupation):
                    Occupation = reader.Value; // for an int, you could do: int.Parse(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case "ComplicatedClass": // if you need to serialize complicated class member then you could do this:
                    // you'd have to not do the reader.Read() above...
                    // DataContractSerializer complicatedClassSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ComplicatedClass));
                    // ComplicatedClass foo = complicatedClassSerializer.ReadObject(reader) as ComplicatedClass;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
         writer.WriteElementString(nameof(Occupation), Occupation.ToString());

         //for a more complicated  type than string, int etc:
         //DataContractSerializer complicatedClassSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(complicatedClass));
         //complicatedClassSerializer.WriteObject(writer, new ComplicatedClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: does anyone have a good link explaining why `GetSchema()` returns null? I was simply told "It always, ALWAYS returns null."

Answer (score 1):

When you do `new List<int>(3)`, you are setting the *initial capacity*, not the number of elements. There are still zero elements, so `_myList[0]` etc will all fail until you `Add` the appropriate number of elements. This contrasts to arrays, as `new int[3]` *always has* exactly 3 elements (which will be `null` initially).

Frankly, there's no need for a list here at all, if you are trying to hard-code them to positions - just use simple properties:

```cs
[DataMember]
public string Occupation {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I'll make it an array really quick. You are totally correct that it's not needed in this case anyways, I'm just trying to make a quick simple example, but I may have simplified it to far.

Comment: @bwall I see you've updated it to change to an array; is it still failing? note: DCS has the ability to bypass constructors if it chooses, which means an array field wouldn't get initialized

Comment: Make your myList readonly; (remove the set; from the definition); than you can be sure nobody is every modifying the array to anything else; you initialize it twice right now with new string[3];

Comment: @MarcGravell, you are right, it is still bypassing the constructor and not initializing :(